# How to find the closest number from summed numbers with showing which numbers are used

Tags: python, pandas, list, random, helper

I'm doing a project where I have a list of number random numbers get choosen from it:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in range(5):
    first = int(random.choice(list))
    second = int(random.choice(list))
    third = int(random.choice(list))
    sumofall = (first + second + third)
```

And It sums the random numbers and gives a result as 'int' and I have str that gives which numbers summed to get that result like:

```
    which_num = str(first) + ' + ' + str(second) + ' + ' + str(third) #Equals 7
```

As it showen in the 1st code i want to find its result and which numbers are summed to find it and from the results like: 9, 12, 8. I want to find the which of the result is the closest to this int and also show which numbers are summed to get that result

Want result like

```
list of summed numbers: 9, 12 ,8, 10, 13

I want the number closest to 14
It prints/shows:
Closest one is: 13
Summed these: 2 + 5 + 6
```

Maybe it can be solved easier with pandas but I'm not sure

Comment: Just a note to your code: Use different name for your list variable. This way you overwrite Python's inbuilt function `list`.

Comment: Where do you get the 14 from?

Comment: A number I chose isn't related with code @NirElbaz

Comment: Does the list always contain the numbers 1-9?

Comment: Closest one is quite simple , save the results to a list, sort it and do a binary search on it

Comment: @Vlad number usually like 14647726714611, 13291549682617 it has a list on .txt

Comment: for the sum - do you have to choose 3 numbers? can you do less or more?

Comment: @NirElbaz I didn't figure out how to show which numbers are used to sum that number

Comment: @NirElbaz In my case there are 50 large numbers and it sums 8 of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store in dictionary to simply the approach,

```
def closest(n, lst):
    return min(lst, key=lambda x: abs(x - n))

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
d = {}
for i in range(5):
    vals = vals = [random.choice(lst) for _ in range(3)]
    d[sum(vals)] = vals

print(f'list of summed numbers: {list(d.keys())}')
print(f'I want the number closest to {14}')

closed_one = closest(14, d.keys())

print(f'Closest one is: {closed_one}')
print(f'Summed these: {d[closed_one]}')
```

Output:

```
list of summed numbers: [18, 7, 10, 5, 15]
I want the number closest to 14
Closest one is: 15
Summed these: [5, 9, 1]
```

**EDIT**
As Vald mentioned, there if there is a duplication dictionary will override the key exiting. So you can do an approach like this,

```
def closest(n, lst):
     return min(lst, key=lambda x: abs(int(x.split("_")[1]) - n)) 
 
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
d = {}
for i in range(5):
     vals = vals = [random.choice(lst) for _ in range(3)]
     d[f"{i}_{sum(vals)}"] = vals
 
print(f"list of summed numbers: {list(map(lambda x: x.split('_')[1], d.keys()))}")
print(f"I want the number closest to {14}")
 
closed_one = closest(14, d.keys())

print(f"Closest one is: {closed_one.split('_')[1]}")
print(f"Summed these: {d[closed_one]}")
```

Output

```
list of summed numbers: ['21', '15', '20', '17', '18']
I want the number closest to 14
Closest one is: 15
Summed these: [5, 6, 4]
```

Comment: Ty for your answer it give TypeError on "d[sum(vals)] = vals" unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @jetrldz What is the input you gave for `lst`?

Comment: @RahulKP Your *for* loop populating the dictionary is flawed because the sum of the selected values may cause duplication and hence the dictionary is not guaranteed to contain 5 key/value pairs

Answer (score 1):

Without trying to format the output or figuring out where the input values come from, here's an approach that may be useful...

```
from random import choice

NSELECTIONS = 5
NVALS = 3

list_of_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

selected_values = {}

while len(selected_values) < NSELECTIONS:
    t = [choice(list_of_numbers) for _ in range(NVALS)]
    selected_values[sum(t)] = t

nearest_to = 14

kv = min(selected_values, key=lambda x: abs(x-nearest_to))

print(kv, selected_values[kv])
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the sum in an array with the index of summed number
it is better to use random.randint

```
    from json.encoder import INFINITY
    from ntpath import join
    import random
    
    
    number = 14
    list_of_sum = []
    list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    for i in range(5):
        first_index = random.randint(0,len(list)-1)
        second_index = random.randint(0,len(list)-1)
        third_index = random.randint(0,len(list)-1)
        first = list[first_index]
        second = list[second_index]
        third = list[third_index]
        sum = first + second + third
        list_of_sum.append([sum,[first_index,second_index,third_index]])
        which_num = str(first) + ' + ' + str(second) + ' + ' + str(third)  + ' = ' + str(sum)
        print(which_num)
    
    items_of_sum = ','.join([str(item[0])  for item in list_of_sum])
    print('list of summed numbers: ' + items_of_sum + '\n')
    
    
    start_value = INFINITY
    numbers_index = 0
    sum_index = 0
    for i in range(5):
        sub = abs(list_of_sum[i][0] - number)
        if sub < start_value:
            start_value = sub
            sum_index = i
            numbers_index = list_of_sum[i][1]
    
    
    
    print('Closest one is: ' +  str(list_of_sum[sum_index][0]))
    
    print('Summed these: ' +  ','.join([str(list[index])  for index in numbers_index]))
```

---